# Looking for Export two report in one powershell Get-Mailbox | Get-mailboxpermission

Tags: powershell

I am working with 5000 users in a csv file, I want to check that each has a service account applied as full-access to their mailbox.

I want to output this result along with their email and display name into a CSV file.

So far my code is this:

```
Get-Mailbox -abc.xyz@test.com | Select Displayname,email

Import-csv c:\test1.csv | foreach { get-MailboxPermission $_.Name -User "SVC-EX-@test.onmicrosoft.com"}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you want to do?

Comment: I want to combine get-mailbox result and get-mailboxpermission result in one powershell

Comment: can you add the contents of the `csv` or sample content to your question ?

Comment: What do you mean with one powershell? In one script? In one command?

Comment: So it will display User Display name and email using Get-mailbox and also display who has full access to that user mailbox in one command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Import-csv c:\test1.csv | ForEach-Object { 
    $MailBox = Get-Mailbox -Identity $_.Name
    $Permission = ($MailBox | Get-MailboxPermission -User "SVC-EX-@test.onmicrosoft.com").AccessRights

    $Properties = @{
        Name = $MailBox.DisplayName
        Email = $MailBox.PrimarySmtpAddress
        Permissions = $Permission
    }
    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties
}
```

Comment: Thank You for your quick response